# Data Attribute Selectors and jQuery

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I have a group of items with a data attribute that contains an array of categories:

```
<div class="result" data-categories="category-1, category-2, category-3" data-type="logo" data-preview="images/previews/preview.jpg">
```

I'm having trouble selecting elements WITHOUT the value that I'm passing in, from the data-categories group.

```
$(".media-results .result:not([data-categories*=" + val + "])");
```

This seems to work ok, but when I change the select element that uses this selector, I get strange, undesirable results(the selector seems to run infinitely and the page keeps hiding and showing elements at random).

Any help from anyone?

---

Edit: here is the function that the select passes the value to:

```
allResults.animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 500, function(){
        console.log("Change triggered. All results hidden.");
        notSelected.hide(50, function(){
            console.log("Unwanted items hidden");
            selected.show().animate({ opacity: "1" }, 500);
        });
    });
```

Comment: *"array of categories"* -> list of categories -- I suspect the issue has nothing to do with the above code, but with the code you're handling the select with.

Comment: The select only exists to pass a value to the "filter" function, which I've added to the question. I have no trouble getting and passing the value from the select, I am having problems using that value to select the correct elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter()`

```
elements = $(".media-results .result").filter(function(){
    return $(this).data("categories").indexOf(val) == -1
});
```